How To Bind ObservableList item to DataTemplate
I have a problem with binding list's items to the property. I have an ObservableList<Product> and I want to bind a Product itself to a property, not a Product's properties. Is it possible to pass the whole list's object, not the object's properties?
I can do this:
<ListView x:DataType="local:ViewModel.AddItemByNameViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Models.Product">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <local:ProductView ProductName="{Binding Name}" Proteins="{Binding Proteins}" Fat="{Binding Fat}" Carbohydrates="{Binding Carbohydrates}" ProductImageSource="{Binding ProductImage}" Kcal="{Binding Kcal}">

                        </local:ProductView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

But I want to do somthing like this:
<ListView x:DataType="local:ViewModel.AddItemByNameViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Models.Product">
            <ViewCell>
                <local:ProductView Product="{Binding Product} <!--what should I place here?-->">

                </local:ProductView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


What's the type of Product property in the ProductView?

use {Binding .} to bind the entire object

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Type of the Product is Product - it is my class

@Jason it doesn't work unfortunately :/

That is how you bind an object.  I've done it hundreds of times.  If its not working then something else must be going on, in ProductView or elsewhere

@Jason you were right, there was a problem in different place too

Could you please add the relevant code for ProductView in your post? It may help us reproduce the question.

Based on @Jason comments and my tests, the correct answer to my question is this.
To bind an item of the ObservableList<T> to a <DataTemplate> by <ListView> u need to bind your element in <ViewCell> in this way {Binding .}.
So in my case, it would look like this:
<ListView x:DataType="local:ViewModel.AddItemByNameViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Grid.Row="3">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Models.Product">
            <ViewCell>
                <local:ProductView Product="{Binding .}">
                    
                </local:ProductView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

